# Remove Icons from Eclipse Oxygen IDE

Tags: eclipse

My IDE Release 4.7.0 (Oxygen) has many Icons like these:

[image]

Is there a way to customize the view?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for: Edit the toolbar icons or replace the icon set.

Comment: Yeah I want to remove the icons. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' dialog on the 'Tool Bar Visibility' tab you can enable or disable various groups of the tool bar buttons.

Comment: Thanks you, exactly what I needed